# BeautifulSoup Find within an instagram html page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, find, instagram

---

### I have a problem to find something with bs4.

I'm trying to automatically find some urls in an html instagram page and *(knowing that I'm a python noob)* I can't find the way to search automatically within the html source code the urls who are in the exemple after the `"display_url": http..."`.

> I want to make my script search multiples url who appears as next as "display_url" and download them.
>   They have to be extracted as many times as they appear in the source code.

---

With bs4 I tried the :

```
f = urllib.request.urlopen(fileURL)
htmlSource = f.read()
soup = bs(htmlSource, 'html.parser')
metaTag = soup.find_all('meta', {'property': 'og:image'})
imgURL = metaTag[0]['content']
urllib.request.urlretrieve(imgURL, 'fileName.jpg')
```

But I can't make the `soup.find_all(...` work/search it.
Is there a way for me to find this part of the page with bs4 ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is an exemple of my little (python) code as it is now : https://repl.it/@ClementJpn287/bs

```html
<!––cropped...............-->

<body class="">

  <span id="react-root"><svg width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 50 50" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-25px 0 0 -25px;fill:#c7c7c7">
      <path
        d="

        <!––deleted part for privacy -->

         " />
      </svg></span>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    window._sharedData = {
      "config": {
        "csrf_token": "",
        "viewer": {
        
        <!––deleted part for privacy -->
   
        "viewerId": ""
      },
      "supports_es6": true,
      "country_code": "FR",
      "language_code": "fr",
      "locale": "fr_FR",
      "entry_data": {
        "PostPage": [{
          "graphql": {
            "shortcode_media": {
              "__typename": "GraphSidecar",
     
     <!––deleted part for privacy -->
     
              "dimensions": {
                "height": 1080,
                "width": 1080
              },
              "gating_info": null,
              "media_preview": null,

<--There's the important part that have to be extracted as many times it appear in the source code-->

              "display_url": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/",
              "display_resources": [{
                "src": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/",
                "config_width": 640,
                "config_height": 640
              }, {
                "src": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/",
                "config_width": 750,
                "config_height": 750
              }, {
                "src": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/",
                "config_width": 1080,
                "config_height": 1080
              }],
              "is_video": false,
       
<!––cropped...............-->
```

[my newest code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JksMN.jpg)

Comment: Do you have a couple of example urls to work with?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes any page post page who contains multiples pictures (in the carousel style) but the pages are generated by intagram with our unique user token so I can't really pass it to you as they are... :(

Comment: Yes so for that I tried to add an part of a source code... ^^

Comment: grab the appropriate script tag and regex it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem Solved

Here's the code to download multiples images from an instagram url with Pythonista 3 on iOS:

```
    from sys import argv
    import urllib
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
    import re
    import photos
    import clipboard


    thepage = "your url"
#p.1
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(html)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    print(soup.title.text)
    txt = soup.select('script[type="text/javascript"]')[3] 
    texte = txt.get_text()
    fille = open("tet.txt", 'w')
    fille.write(texte)
    fille.close()
#p.2
    g = open('tet.txt','r')
    data=''.join(g.readlines())
    le1 = 0
    le2 = 0
    hturl = open('url.html', 'w')
    still_looking = True
    while still_looking:
        still_looking = False
        dat = data.find('play_url', le1)
        det = data.find('play_resources', le2)
        if dat >= le1:
            #urls.append(dat)
            le1 = dat + 1
            still_looking = True                
        if det >= le2:
            hturl.write(data[dat:det])
            le2 = det + 1
            still_looking = True
    hturl.close()
#p.3
    hturl2 = open('url.html', 'r')
    dete = ''.join(hturl2.readlines())
    le11 = 0
    le22 = 0
    urls = []
    still_looking2 = True
    while still_looking2:
        still_looking2 = False
        dat2 = dete.find('https://scontent-', le11)
        det2 = dete.find('","dis', le22)
        if dat2 >= le11:
            urls.append(dat2)
            le11 = dat2 + 1
            still_looking2 = True                
        if det2 >= le22:
            urls.append(dete[dat2:det2])
            le22 = det2 + 1
            still_looking2 = True   
    hturl2.close()
#p.4
    imgs = len(urls)
    nbind = imgs
    nbindr = 3 
    images = 1
    while nbindr < imgs:
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(urls[nbindr], 'photo.jpg')
        photos.create_image_asset('photo.jpg')
        print ('Image ' + str(images) + ' downloaded')
        nbindr = nbindr +2
        images += 1
    print("OK")
```

It's a bit fastidious but it's working and rapidly too.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could find the appropriate script tag and regex out the info. I have assumed the first script tag containing `window._sharedData =` is the appropriate one. You can fiddle as required.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re

html = '''
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body class=""> 
  <span id="react-root">
   <svg width="50" height="50" viewbox="0 0 50 50" style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;margin:-25px 0 0 -25px;fill:#c7c7c7"> 
    <path d="

        <!––deleted part for privacy -->

         " /> 
   </svg></span> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window._sharedData = {
      "config": {
        "csrf_token": "",
        "viewer": {

        <!––deleted part for privacy -->

        "viewerId": ""
      },
      "supports_es6": true,
      "country_code": "FR",
      "language_code": "fr",
      "locale": "fr_FR",
      "entry_data": {
        "PostPage": [{
          "graphql": {
            "shortcode_media": {
              "__typename": "GraphSidecar",

     <!––deleted part for privacy -->

              "dimensions": {
                "height": 1080,
                "width": 1080
              },
              "gating_info": null,
              "media_preview": null,

<--There's the important part that have to be extracted as many times it appear in the source code-->

              "display_url": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/",
              "display_resources": [{
                "src": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/",
                "config_width": 640,
                "config_height": 640
              }, {
                "src": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/",
                "config_width": 750,
                "config_height": 750
              }, {
                "src": "https://scontent-cdt1-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/",
                "config_width": 1080,
                "config_height": 1080
              }],
              "is_video": false,</script>
 </body>
</html>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
scripts = soup.select('script[type="text/javascript"]')
for script in scripts:
    if ' window._sharedData =' in script.text:
        data = script.text
        break
r = re.compile(r'"display_url":(.*)",')
print(r.findall(data))
```

---

Thanks to @t.h.adam it may be possible to shorten the above to:

```
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
r = re.compile(r'"display_url":(.*)",')
data = soup.find('script', text=r).text
print(r.findall(data))
```

Comment: You can make your code shorter if you use your regex as a `text` parameter in `.find()`, eg: `data = soup.find('script', text=r).text`

Comment: You're very welcome! Sometimes it's best to use `.find()`/`.find_all()` because they accept regular expressions and functions.

Comment: Hi. As I tried the @t.h.adam idea in my software the outcome became : File "main.py", line 27, in <module>
    soup = bs(soup1, 'lxml')
  File "/home/runner/.site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 244, in __init__
    markup = markup.read()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.

Comment: is the data dynamically loaded? print soup and verify

Comment: Can't print it because :  

`in <module>
    soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
  File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/93F4D70C-FD37-45C8-80BD-F48B0E2BCCB3/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 158, in __init__
    % ",".join(features))
bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

Comment: change lxml for html.parser

Comment: Sorry how does that link? I am using requests

Comment: how does your code comment relate to my answer please?

Comment: Sorry I tought that that was there for expliciting the advancement of my project but I corrected my fault with the new answer :( [so I deleted my false comments]

Answer (score 0):

The program advanced and it became something like this :

```
thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(html)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    print(soup.title.text)
    txt = soup.select('script[type="text/javascript"]')[3] 
    texte = txt.get_text()
    f1 = open("tet.txt", 'w')
    f1.write(texte)
    f1.close() 
    with open('tet.txt','r') as f:
        data=''.join(f.readlines())
    print(data[data.index('"display_url":"'):data.index('","display_resources":')+1])
```

But now something new appeared :

- How to make the finding url part of the program (line 10, 11) repeat as long as the **('** "display_url":" *to -->* ","display_resources": **')** appear in the *tet.txt* file ?
- The ***while loop*** can be used but how to make it repeat the process ?