# How to repeat a .index search multiple times

Tags: python, search

### Hello

I have [a code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191164/beautifulsoup-find-within-an-instagram-html-page) that's going to search multiples times a string as long as the string appears in a .txt file and I'm obligated to use this form to search the strings :
`data[data.index('"display_url":"'):data.index('","display_resources":')+1]`.

- How can I make it run and add the string that it find to my list (as long as it appears in the .txt) ?

The real part of the code :

```
urls = []  
g = open('tet.txt','r') data=''.join(g.readlines())
dat = (data[data.index('"display_url":"'):data.index('","display_resources":')+1])
urls.append(dat) 
g.close() 
print(urls)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This question may be helpful to reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664850/find-all-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-python

Comment: I will try, thanks. I will make it the answer if I make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative found here :

[Find A->B strings multiples times with a while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55423117/11210823)