# Find A->B strings multiples times with a while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, find, readfile

### Hello

I'm on a project who require me to **find a string interval multiples times** (from *display_url* to *display_resources*) in a .txt file. 
For now I have my code like this but when I'm running it, **it never break**.

The goal of this code is to :

1. Search the strings from the *le1* / *le2* index as starting point.
2. Update the new found index from the *dat* / *det* variables to *le1* / *le2* [to go to the next string interval in the .txt file (in my test they are four of them)]
3. Add the *le1* & *le2* variables to the *urls* list.
4. Loop as long as *dat* & *det* doesn't returns -1.
5. Print all of the combination of *le1* and *le2* obtained in the *urls* list.

It will help a lot to have your thoughts thanks.

---

```
    urls = []
    g = open('tet.txt','r')
    data=''.join(g.readlines())
    count = 0
    le1 = 1
    le2 = 1


    while count >= 0 :
        dat = data.find('display_url', le1)
        det = data.find('display_resources', le2)
        if dat < le1: 
            le1 = le1 +dat
        if det < le2:
            le2 = lez +det
        urls.append(le1)
        urls.append(le2)
        if dat <= 0 :
            count = -1
            break

    print(urls)
```

Comment: what have you done to debug it? (e.g. have you printed out `locals()` inside the loop to see how the variables change?)

Comment: ps: step 4 in your description doesn't seem to be in your code...?

Comment: pps: without sample input and expected output, nobody is going to be able to help you.

Comment: No I don't know how to place it ? (Sorry I'm a noob in this) I can try to add some print() in the loop to see what's done by the program.

Comment: ps: isn't print(urls) the 4 step ?

Comment: PPS: the input are [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55191164/11210823) and for the outputs I'm waiting for a list of index integers = (xxx, yyy, xxx, yyy, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `'display_url'` and `'display_resources'` are in the string initially, your three `if` statements never get triggered. You want something like the following, that records det and dat at each step and starts searching again from that point. The while loop goes until both if statements fail.

```
le1 = 0
le2 = 0
still_looking = True
while still_looking:
    still_looking = False
    dat = data.find('display_url', le1)
    det = data.find('display_resources', le2)
    if dat >= le1:
        urls.append(dat)
        le1 = dat + 1
        still_looking = True                
    if det >= le2:
        urls.append(det)
        le2 = det + 1
        still_looking = True
```

with

```
data = "somestuffdisplay_url some more stuff display_resources even more stuff display_url lastly more stuff still, can you believe it?"
```

returns:

```
[9, 37, 71]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot you are a lifesaver.